# How to retrieve the images from the particular folder?

Tags: android, image, listview

I am trying to take picture and save it in a particular folder and retrieve it in a list view. I have done the first part that is show to store it in  a particular folder, but I don't know how to retrieve it.

Here the taken images is stored in a hello camera folder which is inside pictures. The below code can also record the video. Please give me the code to retrieve the images only from the particular folder. I need this code because to store the documents with security.

My code for storing images

```
public class photo extends Activity {


    // Activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    // directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";



    Button submit;
    Context context;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);

        context = this;

        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imagename);
        //n1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imagename);


//        final String Uname = name.getText().toString();

        /**
         * Capture image button click event
         */
        Calendar cal;
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        String currDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        mydb = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DataProvider.DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor cs = mydb.rawQuery("select  * from '" + DataProvider.TBL_PRE + "'", null);




//        cs = getContentResolver().query(DataProvider.PRE_URI, null,DataProvider.DATE+"="+currDate, null, null);


        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // capture picture
                captureImage();
            }
        });


      submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String err = val();
                if (err.length() <= 0) {

                    String uname = name.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("++uname--->" + uname);
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(DataProvider.NAME1, uname);
                    getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.PRE_URI, values);
                    System.out.println("\n values" + values.toString());
                    startActivity(new Intent(photo.this, preview.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);




                }
               else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.setMessage(err);
                    alertDialog.show();

                }

            }
        });

      /*submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String err = val();
                if (err.length() <= 0) {

                    String uname = name.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("uname--->" + uname);
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(DataProvider.NAME1, uname);
System.out.println("^^^"+uname);

                    //values.put(DataProvider.DATE, date.getText().toString());
                    getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.PRE_URI, values);
                    System.out.println("\n values" + values.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(photo.this, preview.class);
                    startActivity(i);}
            }


        });

*/


        /**
         * Record video button click event
         */
        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                recordVideo();
            }
        });

        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }


    }

    /**
                 * Checking device has camera hardware or not
                 * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
     */
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }

    /**
     * Recording video
     */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file

        // name

        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {
            // hide video preview
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Previewing recorded video
     */
    private void previewVideo() {
        try {
            // hide image preview
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
            // start playing
            videoPreview.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
     * */

    /**
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        startActivity(new Intent(photo.this,preview.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left,R.anim.push_out_right);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }


    public String val() {
        String err = "";

        if (name.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
            err += "Enter the Name \n";
        }




        return err;
    }

}


        // name

        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {
            // hide video preview
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Previewing recorded video
     */
    private void previewVideo() {
        try {
            // hide image preview
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
            // start playing
            videoPreview.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
     * */

    /**
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        startActivity(new Intent(photo.this,preview.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left,R.anim.push_out_right);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }


    public String val() {
        String err = "";

        if (name.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
            err += "Enter the Name \n";
        }




        return err;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve images of particular folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858694/retrieve-images-of-particular-folder-in-android)

Comment: Please take a moment to learn the formatting tools here: paragraph text does _not_ go in a code block, and code _does_ go in a code block.

Comment: Note also that _Stack Overflow_ is not a clearing-house for free labour, and thus questions that are of the form "Please give me the code" are off-topic here.

Comment: help me please...am not able to retrieve the images..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  private void getImages() {
    String[] filenames = new String[0];
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Favorite");// add here your fo;der name
    if (path.exists()) {
        filenames = path.list();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
        imagesPathArrayList.add(path.getPath() + "/" + filenames[i]);
        Log.e("FAV_Images", imagesPathArrayList.get(i));


 //Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.decodeFile(path.getPath()+"/"+ fileNames[i]);
        ///Now set this bitmap on imageview
    }
}
```

don't forget to add permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: what is imageAdapter ..am getting error...can u please give me the full code

Comment: @shwettha sorry  remove that line

Comment: imagesPathArrayList: cannot resolve error...pls help me

Comment: declare arraylist at top of your activity like this

Comment: ArrayList<String> imagesPathArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: can u say me..how to retrieve the images in listview please

Comment: pass the arraylist to you imagview simple

Comment: hey...my project is to capture the image and display it in a other activity in list view as thumb nail image dynamically....is it possible?

Comment: yup it is possible when capture the image just add it image uri or path in to arraylist and pass arraylist to other activity

Comment: sorry yar!!I dont know to to pass the image uri or path...my images are stored in /Pictures/Hello Camera...How to pss the image uri and where should i give it....Can u please help me...am working on this for past 2 days

Comment: than use my above function to get image from your folder  than display it in listview or recyclerview

Comment: @shwettha where do you stuck

Comment: i just captured the image and saved in the Hello Camera Folder...now i need to retrieve the captured image dynamically in other activity  in the listview

Comment: 1. did you try my above function to retrieve images
2. did you run time add permission

Comment: can i send u my code ..and can u please say me where should i insert this code

Comment: can i mail u...?

Comment: yup you should use recyclerview instead of listview

Comment: sir..i mailed u...have u received my mail...i mailed to rathodnilsrk@gmail.com....please help me sir

Comment: ohk i will send you a demo code of retrive image from specif folder using recyclerview ohk